# Show TOP 1 considering where condition if present -SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-join, outer-apply

I have a case where I am using a `OUTER APPLY` query as below

```
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CUSTOMER_CATEGORY 
    FROM   [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] UVFS
    WHERE  UVFS.CUSTOMER_ID = ss.CUSTOMER_ID
) SFD
```

But I have new requirement where `OUTER APPLY` should happen based on considering `customer_category = 'General'` if present.

Pseudo code will be like as below

```
if (Any Item present in [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] with CUSTOMER_CATEGORY=="General' for the specific customer)
{
    SELECT TOP 1 CUSTOMER_CATEGORY 
    FROM   [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] UVFS
    WHERE  UVFS.CUSTOMER_ID = ss.CUSTOMER_ID
    AND UVFS.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY LIKE '%General%'
}
ELSE
{
    SELECT TOP 1 CUSTOMER_CATEGORY 
    FROM   [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] UVFS
    WHERE  UVFS.CUSTOMER_ID = ss.CUSTOMER_ID
}
```

Can anyone suggest better way to rewrite outer apply code in efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine your conditions by adding an order by clause to your `outer apply` query to prioritise `CUSTOMER_CATEGORY = 'General'` e.g.

```
select top 1 CUSTOMER_CATEGORY
from [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] UVFS
where UVFS.CUSTOMER_ID = ss.CUSTOMER_ID
order by case when UVFS.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY like '%General%' then 1 else 0 end desc
```

The result of the case expression when `CUSTOMER_CATEGORY like '%General%'` is 1 and 0 otherwise. We then `order by` the result of the case expression in a descending manner i.e. highest to lowest. In summary this means that if the `CUSTOMER_CATEGORY like '%General%'` it will select selected as a priority.

To further understand how this works consider the results produced by:

```
declare @Id int = 1; -- Choose a Customer ID to test with

select *
    , case when UVFS.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY like '%General%' then 1 else 0 end desc OrderBy
from [UX_VW_CUSTOMER_DETAILS] UVFS
where UVFS.CUSTOMER_ID = @Id
order by case when UVFS.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY like '%General%' then 1 else 0 end desc
```

Comment: i have updated my question.CUSTOMER_CATEGORY  LIKE '%General%'

Comment: no..i have updated the question .I am returning CUSTOMER_CATEGORY

Comment: @Dale..i have doubt on this part "then 1 else 0 desc"..what it indicates ?

Comment: I am getting syntex error while executing above query..Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'

Comment: @Dale..Thank you so much for ur help...i wil test it and will mark as answer